# Need help with Regex to extract zip code from string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract the zip code from a string. The string looks like this:

```
Sandviksveien 184, 1300 Sandvika
```

How can I use regex to extract the zip code?
In the above string the zip code would be 1300.

I've tried something along the road like this:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(", [0..9]{4} ");
string str = "Sandviksveien 184, 1300 Sandvika";
string[] substring = pattern.Split(str);
lblMigrate.Text = substring[1].ToString();
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

> `,\s(\d{4})`

And here is a brief example of how to use it:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String input = "Sandviksveien 184, 1300 Sandvika";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@",\s(\d{4})",
            RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

        Match match = regex.Match(input);

        if (match.Success)
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, it looks like this works :) Need some more testing first :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for *Grouping* that you can do with RegExes...

For an example...

```
Regex.Match(input, ", (?<zipcode>[0..9]{4}) ").Groups["zipcode"].Value;
```

You might need to modify this a bit since I'm going off of memory...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var strs = new List<string> { 
"ffsf 324, 3480 hello",
"abcd 123, 1234 hello",
"abcd 124, 1235 hello",
"abcd 125, 1235 hello"
};

Regex r = new Regex(@",\s\d{4}");

foreach (var item in strs)
{
    var m = r.Match(item);
    if (m.Success)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Found: {0} in string {1}", m.Value.Substring(2), item);
    }
}
```