# How do I extract the zip code parameter from a text sent to my Twilio number?

Tags: c#, twilio, webhooks

Would the Request.Form["FromZip"] function call work for retrieving the zip code parameter from the text message?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Twilio.AspNet.Common;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.TwiML;    

[HttpPost]
public TwiMLResult Index(SmsRequest request)
{
// https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request
// TODO: Request the number that the message was sent from.
// requestFrom = Request.Form["From"];
var requestBody = Request.Form["Body"];

// TODO: Request other "from" location data. (Geographic Data-related parameters)
var requestFromZip = Request.Form["FromZip"];

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it will be in Request.Form? Did Twilio documentation mention this?

Comment: I know var requestBody = Request.Form["Body"]; works since another programmer verified this particular code statement.  Although I couldn't find anything in the Twilio documentation about this Request object.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with C#.  I edited the code to include all the other libraries from the original code base.  Would the Request.Form method be coming from these other libraries that I added from the code base?

Comment: Did you try to read the form values using parameters/model?
Like 
```public TwiMLResult Index([FromForm] string body, [FromForm] string fromzip, ...)```
or (better) use the model SmsRequest
```public TwiMLResult Index([FromForm] SmsRequest request)```

Comment: And are you sure you're getting these data? Because Twilio documentation says the geographic data are optional "Twilio also attempts to look up geographic data based on the 'From' and 'To' phone numbers. Twilio sends the following parameters, if available:"

Comment: The zipcode would be in the body of the HTTP Response.  The body is text and you would need to post the text for help extracting the zip code from the text.

Answer (score 2):

If a user is sending you a message that contains their zip code, then that zip code will be in the `Body` parameter, `Request.Form["Body"]`. You will need to parse the zip code from that string.

You can see the details for the parameters that Twilio sends to your URL as a webhook in the [documentation on Twilio's request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request).

I'm not a C# expert, so I won't try to explain how you might extract the zip code from the string. But [this answer should give you a good idea of how to go about it using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335322/28376).